# $ (\mathbb{Z}, +) $ is a cyclic group. But who generates $0$ (zero) element?

Tags: cyclic-groups, integers

I know that $ (\mathbb{Z}, +) $ is a cyclic group. It is generated by $1$ or by $-1$.

But who generates the $0$ (zero) element?

Thank you!!!!

Comment: So when we are generating the set, we have (1, 1+1, 1+1+1... 1-1, 1-1-1...)? Thank you!!!!!

Comment: Yes, and a more appropriate way to write the above set is : $(1-1, 1, -1, 1+1, -1-1, 1+1+1, -1-1-1,...)$ just to ensure that all integers are present in the set. Because if you write $(1, 1+1, 1+1+1... 1-1, 1-1-1...)$, then the negative integers are actually never reached. Just a notation though.

Comment: Hmm, a second interpretation of "is generated by $1$ or by $-1$" comes to mind. At first I interpreted it as "and", as mentioned in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107259/mathbbz-is-a-cyclic-group-but-who-generatez-0-zero-element#comment4333264_2107265) comment. But now I think it could also mean $\mathbb Z=\langle \{-1,1\}\rangle$. If it is the second interpretation, I can see the current comments and answer being relevant, otherwise I don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every element in $\mathbb{Z}$ can be obtained from a generator $a$ by the groups law, which is addition. However, we also can use the inverse, which is $-a$. This way we obtain every integer for $a=1$ or $a=-1$. In particular we obtain $0=1+(-1)$. For the definition of a "generator" for a group and examples, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group). Often the group law is written $a\circ b$, but for abelian groups the conventions is usually to write addition, i.e., $a\circ b=a+b$, so that $a^{-1}$ is $-a$, and the neutral element $e$ is $0$. The multiplicative version of your question is, how to obtain $e$: as $a\circ a^{-1}$.

Comment: To be honest I don't see how this answers the question. The OP knows that the group is generated by $1$ and $-1$, this means that $\mathbb Z=\{1^k\colon k\in \mathbb Z\}$ and $\mathbb Z=\{(-1)^k\colon k\in \mathbb Z\}$ (with a proper definition of power). What could "who generates $0$?" mean except for what power $k$ yields $0$?

Comment: But this is the same: $e=a\circ a^{-1}=a^0$.

Comment: The exponent in the generator isomorphism indicates composition by the group operation with the generator, not multiplication, unless the group operation is explicitly defined as multiplication.

Answer (score -1):

Remember the definition a cyclic group,
If a group $G$ is cyclic and $x$ is its generator then,
$G=\langle x\rangle=\{x^n|n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$
Similarly for an additive group,
$(G,+)=\langle x\rangle=\{nx|n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Clearly, $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is cyclic and $\mathbb{Z}=\langle1\rangle=\langle-1\rangle$
And $0\in\mathbb{Z}$ also generated by 1 or -1
since, $0\cdot1=0$ or $0\cdot(-1)=0$

Hope it's clear now.